# Define JVM memory limits dynamically

Tags: java, maven, jvm

I have a Maven project and a final command line distribution that run on a variety of rather different computers, from big testing servers, to rather old and memory-limited personal workstations, to tiny virtual machines.

Is there a way to determine the JVM memory options (-Xms, -Xmx) dynamically, depending on the max available on the current host? I'm thinking of some launching script, but it seems there is no standard command ('free' isn't available on OS X, not to mention Windows) and, regarding Maven tests, the ideal would be Maven to be able to establish memory parameters, before forking surefire.

Comment: If you don't set the -Xmx values this is already done by the JVM itself see the Docs of Oracle...Apart from that you need to go for the smallest machine to configure that otherwise it will run on a host with larger host but not on a machine with less memory....Separation is needed between build time and run time of the application for the user...

Comment: Well, it does it the wrong way :-) On my 16Gb laptop, without -Xmx my app crashes as soon as it has consumed something like 1Gb.

What I'd like to do is to evaluate the max available memory before starting any JVM and pass something like 70% of it to -Xmx, so it would adapt to what it finds. I already have an idea of how to do so in Linux, but I'd like to find a portable way (i.e., without multiple OS-specific scripting), the only way I can see so far is to first run a Java program that just reports this information.

Comment: The JVM (As I correctly remember?) defines 1/8 of the physical memory as default. Furthermore do you mean the crash during build time or run time of your app? Consuming a 1 GiB is very huge..Have you checked from this massive memory requirement is coming from?

Comment: 1/8 is very little, my application crashes during run, building isn't usually a big deal (except the integration tests sometimes, when they test large data sets processing). If you think 1GB is huge, probably you don't do things like processing Gene Ontology and other biological data :-)